# How to validate user login and logout using JWT token with Oauth2 in FastAPI using python

Tags: python, fastapi

After logout call, I want to clear/expire the token which is stored in the jwt.

Comment: Provide more details please, maybe some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.